# Wrong email verification

Tags: php, pdo

It's my first post on stackoverflow and I prevent you I don't speak English very well but i can try to be clear on my problem :)

I have a registration form in PHP and i have two Statements :

First Statement : Searching into my table "users" if there's not another pseudo / email for example.

```
$request = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USE_USERNAME = :username AND USE_EMAIL = :email AND USE_PASSWORD = :password");
$request->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$request->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$request->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$request->execute();
var_dump($request);
while ($row = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if ($username == $row['USE_USERNAME']){ ...
```

Second Statement : If the user enters good datas, i can insert inputs into my database.

```
$request = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (USE_USERNAME, USE_EMAIL, USE_PASSWORD) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)");
            $request->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $request->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $request->bindParam(':password', $pass_hache, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $request->execute();
```

**My problem :**

When i insert ***'OR 1=1'*** in an input, i can insert the same e-mail address in the database.

I searched in this website a solution and i added those lines to my database connection :

```
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

But my datas insert even i put error messages in my PHP code (with Javascript popups in my while loop).

I am a beginner, i'm searching to Similar questions, but thank you for your help if you have an answer :)

Have a nice day :)

**Edit** : I will explain you when I manage errors in PHP :

```
while ($row = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if ($username == $row['USE_USERNAME']){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Erreur#5 : Pseudonyme Faux !");  //Cas dans lequel les identifiants sont incorrects.
            document.location.href="subscribe.php";
        </script>
        <?php
        $error++;
```

It's very banal, but i have a variable $error that begins at 0, and I increment it in order to stop the PHP script.

There's errors for an unique Username and email. Before my prepare statements, my errors worked, but now I want prevent my form from SQL Injections.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "i can insert the same e-mail address in the database.". Did you mark the `email` field as unique when creating it?

Comment: If i insert an identic e-mail address in the database when i insert 'OR 1=1' in an input, there's a problem. I will explain it.

Comment: I added more details for the email, thank you a lot for taking time to my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question that have many quirks to it:

1st - you should validate your input with something like 
`filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

2nd - you should place a uniqueness constraint in your database regarding you email with something like 
`ALTER TABLE user ADD UNIQUE unique_index_email (email);`

3rd - your query only returns the email if username and password are also the same. You should query for email only. something like 
`$request = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USE_EMAIL = :email");` 
since this will make sure that if 1 exists, it will be returned

4th - I would strongly advise you not to keep passwords in your database, just keep the hashed values. You have cryptographic strong libs available as php libs, and built in [some](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) that should do the trick

Comment: I added more details for the email, thank you a lot for taking time to my problem :)